# Why are there files in my End and Nether regions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In this world, I haven't visited the End or the Nether yet, so the `/DIM` and `/DIM-1` folders have both been empty.

At some point today, after building a long rail line, I noticed that there is now a 12kb `/region/r.1.1.mca` in *both* folders, even though I haven't been to either dimension! The files are missing in my backup from yesterday, so I know they were just created.

This is a single-player map, so that precludes the possibility of another server user having visited and caused chunks to be generated.

Where did they come from? Why is Minecraft generating chunks for dimensions I haven't visited?

Comment: Probably just generating chunks for the dimensions you haven't visited. Hm, maybe traveling too far caused new nether chunks to generate?

Comment: @avestar101 I wasn't traveling in the Nether, only in the Overworld. I haven't visited the Nether.

Comment: Is this a *problem*? The answer is probably just "because Minecraft did it," and I'm not sure what else we can help you with.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I want to know why, if there's some ingame reason that could affect it, etc. I'm sure there is a valid reason. Don't be such a wet blanket.

Comment: I admit it's surprising, but it's unlikely to affect anything. Curiosity is a good enough reason though! So long as there's no underlying problem that just wasn't mentioned.

Comment: No, I meant that maybe traveling in the overworld somehow generated a chunk. Maybe all portals in the nether connect to a certain chunk (Ex. Portal within certain 5 blocks in the nether connect to certain overworld chunks)

Comment: This question *needs* to be titled "Why are there files in my End and Nether regions?"

Comment: Do you have any portals to either The End or Nether which have been created but not travelled through? Since items can travel through portals, perhaps one popped through, but the entire region won't be generated until you as a player step though.

Comment: Have you ever used the option "Open to LAN"? I believe when MineCraft runs as a server, it opens and keeps the "spawn chunks" of each region loaded (but with limitations) to make travelling between dimensions faster. Perhaps those regions were created when the chunks were being "preloaded"?

Answer (score 1):

Even the Nether and the End have an area similar to the "spawn"-Region in the overworld, I think these areas are even pre-generated even if you dont enter them.

And after you have you first Nether portal, the region on the "other"side of the portal will be loaded too, if you are close the the portal (or if items or monsters touch the portal)

Answer (score -5):

According to Notch, both Nether and The End portals spawn naturally as well. If you happen to "meet" one of these portals, it will automatically generate a single chunk in the corresponding world to be able to place the matching portal in that world.

I'm not entirely sure, even though it seems this way, that if you see one of the two, it does this for both. Notch has never released anything about this.

Comment: Got a **citation** for this (which is not comments about planned development that never happened)? I've never heard of natural Nether portals being programmed in; End portals do of course naturally form in an _incomplete_ state. The shape of a Nether portal could be formed and lit by natural lava flows etc., but it would be extraordinary unlikely.

Comment: Nether portals do not spawn naturally, and they don't generate the other side until you go through.

Comment: At this moment, I'm not finding the citation, however if you look on google ([google]) you will see

Comment: Edit was too late...At this moment, I'm not finding the citation, however if you look on [Google][1] you will see that there are a lot of people encountering this with pre-1.6 singleplayer maps. According to several sources, there was a glitch caused by dieing that generated nether portals. According to other sources, the glitch also glitches and spawns naturally occuring nether portals.

Next time you downvote an answer, tell us why. This helps improving replies. Downvoting because you can is a bad reason..

[1]: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=minecraft+naturally+occuring+nether+portals